# how can I avoid the white background of the iframe before the video is loaded

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I am using the youtube API in my web application and because I'm lazy loading the video iframe, I haven't used the `<iframe>` dom object. Instead, I have given the youtube video ID to a `<div>` tag and then added a static image on top of it.

When the user clicks the image, then the video object will be loaded and played.

The issue I'm having is with a white background which is being displayed for a moment before the video object is done loaded.

I only have this issue with IE.

Javascript:

```
tag = document.createElement('script'), tag.src = '//www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
a.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, a);

var playerID = 0;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
rhsID = $('.video_wrap > div > div > div > div').attr('id'), $('.ytPlyr_1').each(function() {
    $(this).css({
        'background-image': 'url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + this.id + '/mqdefault.jpg)',
        filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + this.id + "/sddefault.jpg',sizingMethod='scale')",
        '-ms-filter': 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=https://i.ytimg.com/vi/' + this.id + "/sddefault.jpg',sizingMethod='scale')"
    }), $(this).append($('<div/>', {
        'class': 'playBtn'
    }));
}), $('.playBtn').click(function() {
    var playedVid = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    loadYTPlayer(playedVid);
}), $('.videos ul').hasClass('video-list') == 1 && $('.video-list').animate({
    height: parseInt(toggleVideoThumList(MAXTOSHOW))
});
}


function loadYTPlayer(a) {

    loadVideo(1, a), getVideoData($(this));
}


function loadVideo(a, b) {
if (null == b) {
    var c = $.trim($('.ytPlyr_' + a).prop('id'));
    addedMultiID[a - 1] = c;
} else var c = b;
player[playerID] = new YT.Player(c, {
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    videoId: c,
    playerVars: {
        rel: 0,
        autoplay: 1,
        wmode: "opaque"
    },
    events: {
        onReady: onPlayerReady,
        onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
    }
}), $('.ytPlyr_' + a).addClass('loaded'), playerID++;
}

function getVideoData(a) {

var b = $.trim($(a).prop('id')),
    c = $(a).prop('src');
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/getYouTubeVideoData',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        videoId: b
    }
}).done(function(a) {
    jQuery.each(a.items, function(a, d) {
        time = d.contentDetails.duration.replace(/\d+/g, function(a) {
            return '0'.substr(a.length - 1) + a;
        }).replace(/[H|M]/g, ':').replace(/[PT|S]/g, ''), time = 2 == time.length ? '00:' + time : time, thumbnail = d.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url, $($($($('#' + b).parent())).find('div.video-desc span.video-time')[0]).text(time), jQuery.each($($('#' + b).parent()).find('meta'), function(a, b) {
            itemprop = $(b).attr('itemprop'), 'duration' == itemprop ? $(b).prop('content', d.contentDetails.duration) : 'thumbnailUrl' == itemprop ? $(b).prop('content', thumbnail) : 'embedUrl' == itemprop ? $(b).prop('content', c) : 'uploadDate' == itemprop && $(b).prop('content', d.snippet.publishedAt);
        });
    });
});
}

function onPlayerReady(a) {
    for (var j = 0; j < player.length; j++) player[j].getIframe().id != a.target.getVideoData().video_id && player[j].getPlayerState() == 1 && player[j].pauseVideo();
}

function onPlayerStateChange(a) {
    console.log("state changed");
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="5dR3Enz5F3s" class="ytPlyr_1 ytplayer"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, unfortunately i'm not able to acess youtube from here but did you try setting a background-image aswelle as a background color to your div ? What element is finally added to your div when the video is loaded ?

Comment: No, it's pointless as it's the video iframe object which is displaying this white background. The `<div>` is not visible when the video is being loaded. @Cr3aHal0

Comment: Okay, then did you try to hide the video until it's fully loaded so then you can show it without seeing the white background of the iframe?

Comment: Yeah I can do that but that's not an option that I want to stick with. It looks just as bad, an empty container while the video is being loaded. @Cr3aHal0